# Unlimited Private Messages

Tags: messages

I see in the Member Groups Preferences(Member -> Member Groups -> Edit Group) that there is an option for "‘Maximum Number of Private Messages a user can store".

If I set it to 0, will this make this unlimited? If not, how do I make it unlimited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting to 0 makes it unlimited.

Thanks to @Bhashkar for the answer

http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/237065/